# aFind and replace keywords in excel file - using python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, jupyter-notebook, find, contains

I am trying to run a python script in Jupyter notebooks

The script I have works if the cell = Bamboo. But I would like the script to work if the cell contains the word "Bamboo" in a sentence or paragraph. Ideally both capital/lowercase.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import openpyxl
replacement_pair = {"Bamboo": " "}
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("wordtest.xlsx")
for ws in wb.worksheets:
for row in ws.iter_rows():
for cell in row:
if cell.value in replacement_pair.keys():
cell.value = replacement_pair.get(cell.value)
wb.save("File without bamboo.xlsx")
```

Can you help me figure this out? The goal is to find and replace multiple values from multiple excel files.

Think... The *find and replace function* in excel, but doing it for multiple values from multiple excel files all at once.

If you have a vba script to do this.. I can also use that

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code to allow it to find ALL keys in dictionary (currently just bamboo, but should work if there are multiple entries in the dictionary) and overwrite with what is in value. It will find the word bamboo even it is part of a larger word or sentence and handle upper/lower case. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import openpyxl
import re
replacement_pair = {"bamboo": " "}
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Sample.xlsx")
i=0
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            for key in replacement_pair: ##Search each key, even if more than just one
                if str(cell.value).lower().find(key.lower()) != -1:
                    OldVal = str(cell.value)
                    remove_word = re.compile(re.escape(key), re.IGNORECASE)
                    cell.value = remove_word.sub(replacement_pair[key], OldVal)
wb.save("File without bamboo.xlsx")
```

Comment: hey @Redox thanks for this. The query is much better at identifying these words. However, I noticed the query is erasing all the text in the cell. I'd like for it to just replace the word "bamboo" in the cell. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Code updated to replace Bamboo with <blank>, keeping other text within the cell as is. Check the penultimate line - `cell.value = str(...`

Comment: hey! thanks. this works!!  However, if the word gets removed, it lowercases the remaining words. Is it possible to keep the item uppercase instead?

Comment: Check now pls...